# How would I "call" an external javascript file onclick?

Tags: javascript

I have an external javascript provided by the service I'm using and in order to implement it I need to "call" a javascript file like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="sciprt src here"></script>
```

Now obviously you can't call a javascript file, but when a user clicks a specific link I need to someone activate this script before the leaving the page. Is this possible?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to load the script on the page earlier (with other Javascript files)?

Comment: @General_Twyckenham I kind of think they don't really understand what they want/need to do. It sounds like they should be loading the script on page load, then calling a function in it when the link is clicked; otherwise the script itself is poorly designed/written.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why you would want to do this.  But this article might help http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml

Comment: You can't call the file after a click. You need to load the file at the beginning, and call a function or link a behavior to the click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why do you need this, but I'm trying to answers your direct question.

This should works (tested in firefox and Chrome)

```
<a href="/mylink/" id="myanchor">Click me</a>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var anchor = document.getElementById("myanchor");

    anchor.addEventListener("click",function(e) {

        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();

        var script = document.createElement('SCRIPT');

        script.onload = function() {
            alert("jquery loaded " + $);
            window.location.href = anchor.href;
        }

        script.src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js";

        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    });
</script>
```

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/3K7UG/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the JavaScript how to page here:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_howto.asp

You can include that script in either the head or body of your HTML and it should load correctly.

Comment: Ah I have not seen this before. I see the "what should be done" section on the page - do you have a favorite resource between those or elsewhere?

Comment: Probably one of the best resources with incredible technical detail is: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web The problem is w3school always comes up in google searches, but they just won't go away!

Comment: Yeah I usually go there first based on search priority. Good to know - thanks :)